# SQL Server JSON output of nested tables

Tags: sql, json, sql-server

I have the following tables:

```
create table students 
(
    id int, 
    name varchar(10)
)    

create table subjects
(
    subjectId int, 
    studentId int, 
    subject varchar(12)
)  

create table marks
(
    studentId int, 
    subjectId int, 
    marks int 
)    

create table sports
(
    sportId int, 
    studentId int, 
    name varchar(12) 
)
```

with the following data:

```
insert into students values(1, 'Rusty');   
insert into subjects values(1, 1, 'math')    
insert into subjects values(2, 1, 'science')    
insert into marks values(1,1,50)    
insert into marks values(1,2,60)    
insert into sports values(1, 1, 'soccer')    
insert into sports values(2, 1, 'baseball')
```

I want to write a query in SQL Server to get the following output:

```
studentId = 1    
{    
    "id": 1,    
    "name": "Rusty",    
    "subjects" : [    
        {    
            "name": "math",    
            "marks": 50    
        },    
        {    
            "name": "science",    
            "marks": 60    
        }    
    ],    
    "sports": [    
        {    
            "name": "soccer"    
        },    
        {    
            "name": "baseball"    
        }    
    ]    
}
```

I tried the following query

```
select *

from students s

join subjects su on (s.id = su.studentId)

join sports sp on (s.id = sp.studentId)

where s.id = 1

for json auto
```

and here is the output:

[

```
{

    "id": 1,

    "name": "Rusty",

    "su": [

        {

            "subjectId": 1,

            "studentId": 1,

            "subject": "math",

            "sp": [

                {

                    "sportId": 1,

                    "studentId": 1,

                    "name": "soccer"

                }

            ]

        },

        {

            "subjectId": 1,

            "studentId": 1,

            "subject": "science",

            "sp": [

                {

                    "sportId": 1,

                    "studentId": 1,

                    "name": "soccer"

                }

            ]

        },

        {

            "subjectId": 1,

            "studentId": 1,

            "subject": "math",

            "sp": [

                {

                    "sportId": 1,

                    "studentId": 1,

                    "name": "baseball"

                }

            ]

        },

        {

            "subjectId": 1,

            "studentId": 1,

            "subject": "science",

            "sp": [

                {

                    "sportId": 1,

                    "studentId": 1,

                    "name": "baseball"

                }

            ]

        }

    ]

}
```

]

Comment: Show us what you have tried.

Comment: Just posted what I tried and the output I got.

Comment: The sample data for marks  and subjects is wrong. You forgot to update the subjectid for both tables. - Edit: Fixed it for you.

Comment: Good catch. Thank you @SchmitzIT. Still trying to figure out how to get the result I am looking for. Using JSON PATH does not help since it gives different format than I am looking for.

Comment: `FOR JSON PATH` is definitely the answer you're looking for. The really-public-not-very-secret-secret to creating nested arrays of objects/values in JSON with Microsoft SQL Server is to use [JSON_QUERY (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/json-query-transact-sql) over subqueries that themselves are outputting JSON.

Comment: JSON_QUERY is to extra  data from json string. I am looking for generating json from data.

Comment: I understand that. Read my comment again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your desired output you can use correlated subqueries for `sports` and `subjects` that generate their own JSON, using [FOR JSON PATH](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/format-query-results-as-json-with-for-json-sql-server#option-1---you-control-output-with-for-json-path), and include that information as an array of nested objects in your main JSON output by way of [JSON_QUERY (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/json-query-transact-sql), e.g.:

```sql
/*
 * Data setup...
 */
create table students (
  id int,
  name varchar(10)
);   
create table subjects (
  subjectId int,
  studentId int,
  subject varchar(12)
);
create table marks (
  studentId int,
  subjectId int,
  marks int
);
create table sports (
  sportId int,
  studentId int,
  name varchar(12)
);
insert into students (id, name) values
  (1, 'Rusty');
insert into subjects (subjectId, studentId, subject) values
  (1, 1, 'math'),
  (2, 1, 'science');
insert into marks (studentId, subjectId, marks) values
  (1,1,50),
  (1,2,60);
insert into sports (sportId, studentId, name) values
  (1, 1, 'soccer'),
  (2, 1, 'baseball');
/*
 * Example query...
 */
select
  students.id,
  students.name,
  json_query(( --<<-- doubled brakcets
    select
      subjects.subject,
      marks.marks
    from subjects
    join marks
      on marks.subjectId = subjects.subjectId
      and marks.studentId = subjects.studentId
    where subjects.studentId = students.id
    for json path
  )) as [subjects],
  json_query(( --<<-- doubled brackets
    select
      sports.name
    from sports
    where sports.studentId = students.id
    for json path
  )) as [sports]
from students
where students.id = 1
for json path, without_array_wrapper;
```

Which yields the JSON output:

```json
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Rusty",
    "subjects": [
        {
            "subject": "math",
            "marks": 50
        },
        {
            "subject": "science",
            "marks": 60
        }
    ],
    "sports": [
        {
            "name": "soccer"
        },
        {
            "name": "baseball"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Question: why do we need to use json_query here. The sql without json_query also gives the same output.

Comment: For this simple case `json_query()` is not actually required, it's just a good habit to get into. In the presence of `union` and `union all` SQL Server can misinterpret `for json` subqueries as string literals, instead of JSON, which leads to such joy as blocks of escaped JSON like `"subjects":"[{\"subject\":\"math\",\"marks\":50},{\"subject\":\"science\",\"marks\":60}]"`